# how to calculate sampling rate for DAC from its data sheet

Tags: integrated-circuit

I need to find the sampling rate of the DAC from its data sheet, could you please suggest me any formulae to find the sampling rate from settling time, no of bits, bandwidth.

As I didn't find sampling rate from the data sheet of DAC's

Comment: Is precision settling your goal? If you have a clean one-pole settling, then each TAU provides another 8.6dB (one neper) improvement in accuracy. For 86dB, you need 10 TAU. If Rload is 100 ohms, and 50pF is the total estimated (Dac Cout + PCB stray + CLoad), then you have 5,000 picoSeconds Tau, and you need to wait 10*5,000pS = 50 nanoseconds. Then there is data-setup time before that important clock edge occurs; probably at least 10 nanoseconds; expect some slewing time?? or de-glitching (at major bit-pattern changes, may be another 20 nanoseconds). We now are up to 80 nanoseconds, or 12MHz.

Comment: Usually the sampling rate is set by the HW driving the DAC. If there is any clock input, then the clock is the sampling rate, probably, or related to the sampling rate in some fashion. I think you should edit your question to include the part number you are using and a link to the datasheet.

Comment: dac8771 is the part number.The datasheet link is http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac8771.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-mousermode-df-pf-null-wwe&DCM=yes&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mouser.in%2F

Comment: Look at fig 1 in the data sheet and do some calcs based on your bit rate and the settling time.

Comment: Please add the part number and link to the original question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

A DAC does not have "a" (one single) sampling rate. It depends on how you use that DAC.

Let's look at the datasheet of a common DAC, I choose the [MCP4725](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/MCP4725.pdf).

I just start reading on the first page.

This DAC is a 12-bits converter

It has a typical settling time of 6 us => Aha, so it needs at least 6 us to "settle down". That means that the time between samples can never be less than 6 us. If we assume we can get a sample every 6 us that means the sampling rate would be 1 second / 6 us = 166 kHz. That's the **absolute fastest** this DAC can do. That is also without any margin so the real speed will be less. I personally would not use this DAC above 100 kHz so 100 kSps.

Then we need to get the data into the DAC and there might be a limitation there as well. The fastest datarate this DAC can do is 3.4 Mbps (Mega bits per second).

The data is send to the DAC in chunks of 2 bytes so that is 16 bits. That means at a datrate of 3.4 Mbps / 16 bits = 212.5 kSps. That's 212.5 kilo samples per second, more than the 100 kSps I recommended above so the datarate of 3.4 MBps is enough to support the 100 ksps.

However at the standard datarate of 100 kbps things will be different, then 100 kbps / 16 bits = 6250 sps (samples per second). The datarate is now so low that the sampling rate must be lower, it is limited by how fast the data is coming in.

Comment: Why you've divided 100kbps/16bits? you've done that before!